return a regular generator from an async function
How can one return a regular (non async) generator from an async function?
async def foo():
 list = await stuff() # expensive io bound here and done.

 for i in list:
    yield i, i*2


for i, j in await foo():
   # regular loop over i and j using the regular generator


Does this work?
